# How to direct psql errors to powershell log file?

Tags: postgresql, windows, powershell, logging

I'm running a `powershell` script on a windows system. The script includes `psql` commands to run SQL on a postgres database.

Most stuff gets correctly recorded in the powershell log file, EXCEPT for `psql` errors.

My powershell script uses this to start logging...

```
$script:logFile = "C:\temp\log\mylog.dat" 

# Start logging to file......
Start-Transcript -Append $script:logFile
```

And then uses `psql` commands to connect to the database and do stuff...

```
.\psql -U myuser -d mydatabase -c "do database stuff here...."
```

This works - in the sense that it executes correctly, but any database errors that appear on the console don't get logged to "C:\temp\log\mylog.dat".

I've tried explicitly logging to the file using this....

```
.\psql -U myuser -d mydatabase -c "do database stuff here...." -L "C:\temp\log\mylog.dat"
```

This doesn't work.

And I've tried re-directing stderr to stdout....

```
.\psql -U myuser -d mydatabase -c "do database stuff here...." 2>&1
```

This doesn't work either.

How do I direct everything from the psql command to the same log file as all the other (non-database) commands in the powershell script?